# Manage User Sessions of two type of (Student and Teacher) in an android app using fire base

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Manage User Sessions of two different kinds of user such as Student and Teacher
so that whenever they exit app without logging out they remain logged in

Comment: Just use FirebaseAuthentication, it handles that. You can store the Students under a key like "students" and same for the teacher or you could just use a Boolean in the database to differentiate between student and teacher. https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

You can create an AppPreference class and create a session for your user type and set you user type like Student and teacher:

```
public class AppPrefrences {
    private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

   public static String getUserType(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getString("UserType", "");
    }

    public static void setUserType(Context ctx, String value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putString("UserType", value);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

set the values when you logged in your app like this:-

if userType is Teacher:

```
setUserType(this, "Teacher");
```

or if userType is Student:

```
setUserType(this, "Student");
```

and get your logged in user type where you need:

```
String userType = getUserType(this);
```